# create dynamic DropDownList in mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a model called question :

```
 public partial class question
    {
        public question()
        {
            this.Indicators = new HashSet<Indicator>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string questionText{ get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Indicator> asnwers{ get; set; }
    }
```

This model have 2 `attributes` called `id` and *questiontext* my model has a relation with `answer` Model .Every question has `1..n` answer .In my answer model i have this :

```
 public partial class answer
    {
        public answer()
        {
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int questionId{ get; set; }
        public string answertext{ get; set; }


        public virtual question ExecutiveOfficer { get; set; }
    }
```

So as you can see every question has 1 or many answer .Let me explain my problem .

I need to show my questions to user in view but my problem is how can i create dynamic `DDL` answers and questions .

My user should be able to answer the dynamic  questions and in controller i should be able to detect each question's answer but i don't know which kind of method should i use?i will  be appreciate if you will give me some help .

I wanted to create `HTML drop down list` and pass them to view but i want to know if therer is a better solution i use that .

Comment: There's lots of examples for MVC cascading dropdownlist, you shouldn't have a problem getting your self started

Comment: @CSharper thank you dear friend but could you give me some example ?

Comment: You could use JQuery and Ajax post to send the answer back to the server. If you want to display another question to the user, you can return a Json object. You will do a $.each(returnObject, function (index, data) { // update your dropdown list here. });